# ESP32 in HomeKit "cmake" must be available on the PATH to use idf.py

Tags: cmake, terminal, esp32, homekit

I wanted to use my ESP32 Cam as camera in Homekit. I found an interesting project which works without bridge, but I have trouble to get it to work. I did in the Terminal on a Mac with MacOS Ventura:

```
cd /Users/<user>/Desktop/Skripte/Mikrocontroller/HomeKit
git clone https://github.com/maximkulkin/esp32-homekit-camera.git
git clone https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf.git
cd /Users/<user>/Desktop/Skripte/Mikrocontroller/HomeKit/esp-idf
sudo sh install.sh
source export.sh
cd /Users/<user>/Desktop/Skripte/Mikrocontroller/HomeKit/esp32-homekit-camera
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

until now everything is fine, but:

```
idf.py build
```

Output:

```
Executing action: all (aliases: build)
ESP-IDF v5.1-dev-3710-gacac972f70
"cmake" must be available on the PATH to use idf.py
```

It should have build the project for my esp32
If I add `/usr/local/Desktop/Skripte/Mikrocontroller/HomeKit/esp-idf/tools/cmake` via `sudo nano /etc/paths`, the output of `idf.py build` changes to `zsh: command not found: idf.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by installing cmake as app and adding it with `PATH="/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin":"$PATH"` to the path